# Git (BitBucket): Received disconnect - Packet corrupt

Tags: php, git, ssh

I am new to Git (on BitBucket) and have been doing okay with it (lots of reading many websites, articles, etc). I however, keep having this issue once my repository grows (as I add stuff to it/write new code), I end up reverting and doing things over and over and getting the same result, can push, can push, then failure.

This is a PHP/codeigniter project and is sitting around 50mb and has a mixture of PHP/CSS/JS. I was thinking files might be corrupt but this just doesn't seem to add up as it keeps happening with different files.

I am on Windows 10, using Git (git version 2.7.0.windows.1), and also phpStorm IDE. I have tried using both HTTPS (did all the http.buffer changes, etc still failed with fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly), then moved to SSH, and now getting this error (basically same thing):

```
Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:(username)/(repo).git
Counting objects: 1855, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1660/1660), done.
Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 2: Packet corrupts
Disconnected from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:(username)/(repo).git'
```

Sufficed to say, I am at a complete loss as to how Git keeps failing me when  I am only trying to do very basic things... I thought it would be helpful to use it to speed some things up and use version control, seems that I spend more time working out Git problems than writing actual code...

Please, please, please do not post up anything about the http.buffer, it does nothing and I am now using SSH anyway...

Comment: I don't think that GIT is the problem here, sounds more like a permissions issue. Could you try creating a new remote repo and pushing to that?

Comment: I am working with a new branch at the moment, if I load the master and create a new branch from it, all it well.. But as soon as I start doing some work and the repo size grows, this is what seems to cause the issue.. Doing this on windows is a little foreign to me as in Linux I would usually go in and set the file permissions recursively with CHMOD and see if this helps (was thinking it may be the problem, but cant see to work out how I would check it).

Comment: `Packet corrupts` comes from ssh, not git, so you could start your investigation from there.

Comment: I am facing an issue from both HTTPS and SSH, so something is going on beyond the protocol being used to send the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted bitbucket support and turns out they are having routing issues from certain ISP's and this is causing the issue. I tethered to my mobile internet and it pushed fine. BitBucket are investigating.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I connected using [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) (London in this case) and it worked perfectly!